Change laravel variable value with javascript
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="parent_category">Category:</label>
    <select id="parent_category" name="parent_category" class="form-control" required>
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            @if ($category->parent_category == null)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $selectedCategoryId = $category->id }}>
                    {{ $category->name }}
                </option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category_id">Sub-Category:</label>
        <select id="category_id" name="category_id" class="form-control" required>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                @if ($category->parent_category == $selectedCategoryId)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
                        {{ $category->name }}
                    </option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var parent_category = document.getElementById('parent_category');

        parent_category.addEventListener('change', function() {
            console.log("changed")
        })
    });
</script>


i need to change $selectedCategoryId according to the user select, how can i do that ??
I have a table with, id, name, parent_id
the parent_id references an id from the table itself, if the value is null it is considered a "parent".
in my first select I want to show only the parents (parent_id = null)
in the second select I want to show the "children" of the selected parent.

Normally you'd use ajax for this.
